# What is 「ピプロシン体」？

Tags: words, etymology, definitions, jargon

This is the first time I've failed to find a word in both dictionaries and Google search: the only hit Google finds is the [article](http://eprints.lib.hokudai.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2115/32514/1/yamamoto.pdf) where this quote appears:

> 「本間さんは頭脳頗る明晰、今後優良の成績で卒業される事となつた、卒業論文は『粉病菌科の分生胞子に就て』と言ふのでウドン粉病胞子の**ピプロシン体**と称する貯蔵物質の化学的成分に関する学術的研究でなか〳〵立派なものだ」

I looked at the Japanese Wikipedia pages on [うどんこ病](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%86%E3%81%A9%E3%82%93%E3%81%93%E7%97%85) and [分生子](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%88%86%E7%94%9F%E5%AD%90) but I could not find any clues. I know that a 分生胞子 (conidium) can be ["pip-shaped."](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=S7I8AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA156&lpg=PA156&dq=life%20cycle%20of%20fungi%20pip&source=bl&ots=Th5FZXIjSQ&sig=uW-Lc4qnVVZsg1UE1hGxEFIIutQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8me2R5pLMAhUBY6YKHT7GDxgQ6AEINjAE#v=onepage&q=pip-shaped&f=false) Could that have any relation to 「ピプロシン」?

My translation of this sentence so far is:

> Honma has an extremely lucid mind and is graduating with high grades;
>   her graduation thesis on *Conidium of Powdery Mildew* is admirable
>   academic research referring to ピプロシン体 as the chemical building blocks of
>   storage material.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Maybe it's supposed to read 「フィブロシン体」?

Comment: @snailboat That looks very promising! Would 「ピプロシン体」 be an outdated but correct form of 「フィブロシン体」?

Comment: I think it's more likely the original text contains an error of some kind.  Compare the same passage quoted in [this PDF from the same archive](http://eprints.lib.hokudai.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2115/45215/1/ARHUA6_004.pdf), where it says ピウロンシン.  My guess is they're both either typos or misreadings or OCR errors or something like that, and they should both refer to [fibrosin bodies](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02860869).

Comment: 粉病菌科 should be today's ウドンコカビ科, that is _Erysiphaceae_ in Latin.

Answer (score 2):

Atually, snailboat is correct.

After all searching of jargons or whatnot, **[I came across this thesis.](http://www.tokyo-aff.or.jp/center/event/koenyoshi_20no10_12.pdf#search='%E3%81%86%E3%81%A9%E3%82%93%E3%81%93%E7%97%85%E8%83%9E%E5%AD%90+%E8%8F%8C+%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%96%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B7%E3%83%B3')**

It says, I am sorr to say I can not translate the sentence since it is too techinical for me,

> OR 菌は， 植物体の表面に分生子を連鎖上に形成します。従来のうどんこ病菌
>   とは分生子や発芽管の形状， **フィブロシン体**という器官を欠く点が異なります
>   （ 図１)。

**[And this site also says,](https://www.naro.affrc.go.jp/flower/kakibyo/plant_search/ka/cosmos/post_63.html)**

> 病原菌は**フィブロシン体**を有する。表生菌糸上に分生子柄を直立し,分生子を鎖生する

I am afraid it is too far over my capability to translate this sentene due to the lack of my knowledge in this field of study.

But it looks like the above says some kind of a vacteria has some stuff so called ***フィブロシン体*** which would probaly cause **[the Powdery mildew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powdery_mildew)** on plants.

Thank you.